# hide the NA values when using display_numbers function in pheatmap

Tags: r, pheatmap

I am plotting heatmap by `pheatmap` package in r.

I applied the `display_numbers` function to display the values in a matrix into the heatmap, and I got:

[heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1I3BY.png)

I got so many NA in my matrix and I would like to hide them in the heatmap, how can I do that?

Comment: Hi @leeleelee please consider editing your question to include sample code, sample data and expected output. You could use `dput(head(mysampledata,20))` to add sample data to your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, it is a lot easier for people to help you if you were to provide reproducible and minimal sample data. Please consider reviewing how to provide a [minimal reproducible example/attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) for future posts.

---

As to your question:

1. Let's generate some sampe data

   ```
   set.seed(2018)
   mat <- matrix(runif(20), 4, 5)
   ```

   We use a second matrix to display values via the argument `display_numbers` of `pheatmap`. Here we simply copy the original matrix and randomly generate some `NA` values:

   ```
   mat2 <- mat
   mat2[mat2 < 0.5] <- NA
   ```
2. We now  replace `NA` values with empty strings.

   ```
   mat2[is.na(mat2)] <- ""
   ```
3. Let's show the heatmap

   ```
   pheatmap(mat, display_numbers = mat2)
   ```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all the advice, I will do my best to ask a good question next time.